# Need to check environment before maven runs unit tests

Tags: maven

First - I'm a novice with maven, I can barely spell it.

We've tracked down a test problem to a missing file that should have been part of the dev's environment. We want to avoid this in the future by verifying this file, and perhaps others, exists prior to running the unit tests. We don't want the file to be a dependency since it is not required for building, just unit testing.

What is the best practice for this? A rather poor illustration of what I am looking for....

```
   <somephase>
      <required>
         <files>
            <file>/some/path/to/some/needed/file</file>
         </files>
      </required>
   </somephase>
```

My searches have come up with nothing. Thanks in advance.

Update - Found this https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFilesExist.html, but I'm not sure when that actually executes. I would rather the check be performed only if unit tests are going to run.

Answer (score 0):

Found this: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFilesExist.html

What I am using...  Note the  tags that skips the plugin if unit tests are skipped.

```
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
           <executions>
              <execution>
                 <id>check-for-cert-file</id>
                 <phase>test-compile</phase>
                 <goals>
                    <goal>enforce</goal>
                 </goals>
                 <configuration>
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                    <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                    <rules>
                       <requireFilesExist>
                          <message>Download the files from the repo</message>
                          <files>
                             <file>/tmp/missingFile</file>
                          </files>
                       </requireFilesExist>
                    </rules>
                 </configuration>
              </execution>
           </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Nothing like "duck programming in stackoverflow.